# It is possible to display a route between two coords launching googlemaps on the navigator? (programatically)

Tags: android, google-maps

I know that i can do it with this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=39.45798340851973,-0.3835865820296931&daddr=39.44353524837272,-0.3760334814437556"));              
            startActivity(intent);
```

But i need to remove the dialog, and forze it to launch navigator ¿how to do it?

I know that i can forze the dialog to open googlemap application with `intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");`

But i need just the opposite, to launch the navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Intent i = new Intent();

i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
Uri data = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
i.setData(data);

startSubActivity(i, 2);
```

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.browser/com.google.android.browser.BrowserActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: also ContentURI doesn't exists

Comment: two errors more: "comp cannot be resolved to a variable"    and     "The method startSubActivity(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: ok, i solved these two errors, it works now! IT OPENS THE NAVIGATOR! but it shows the route with thext, i need to show the route on the map, how to do it?